# how to show certain number of products for guests in magento

Tags: php, magento

I need show 10 or any number products for guest user.
So how to show certain number of products for guests or special users groups in magento?

Comment: More information would be nice, is it for the homepage or a sidebar or ...? If you ask a question, please take your time to explain what you need in order to get quality answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the toolbar block:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

there is a method:

```
public function setCollection($collection);
```

inside there is a piece of code:

```
$limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
if ($limit) {
    $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
}
```

you need to change variable $limit. Of course, you should override that block in local pool, not change directly in core.
you can use this code in order to see whether the customer is guest:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
```

Answer (score 1):

**In the toolbar block you will see:**

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

overriding: assume path:

app/code/local/companyname/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

there is a method:

```
Public function setCollection($collection);
```

Inside there is a piece of code:

```
$limit= (int)$this->get Limit();

If ($limit) {

$this ->_collection->setPageSize($limit);

}
```

**You have to change variable $limit; you should override that block in the local pool, not change directly in the core.  In order to see whether the customer is a guest, you can use this code**

```
Mage:: getSingleton(‘customer/session’) -> isLoggedIn()
```